# How to avoid error on MYSQL CONVERT() method, when passing a 0 second string and subtract from that value?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, mysql-function

I am using MySQL 8 and have a problem with this type of query:
INSERT INTO review (name, create_date) VALUES('name', CONVERT(timestamp, DATETIME) - 1)
I have not had this error when using this expression in a where clause.
When the value for the timestamp is like '2020-12-16 06:15:01' it's working.

But with a value of 0 seconds (like: '2020-12-16 06:15:00') an error is dropped.

```
Incorrect datetime value: '20201216061499' for column 'create_date' at row 1
code: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE
errno: 1292
sqlState: 22007
```

I used this type of expression in my whole project. Is there a simple solution to this problem, without changing each expression?
Is that one a bug?

One solution to this problem is:

```
DATE_SUB(CONVERT(timestamp,DATETIME) INTERVAL 1 SECOND).
```

But as I already mention this requires changing each expression.

Comment: What datatype has the value? Why its numeric representation differs from its string representation? You do not need in CONVERT at all if provided value `'2020-12-16 06:15:00'` is of string type - it will be converted to DATETIME implicitly and correctly.

Comment: PS. Never use double quotes in MySQL queries until quoting JSON paths/values.

Comment: its a string-value. i had to use convert() to perform the - 1 second operation. whithout this a string cannot be processed with minus 1 second

Comment: I am not had this error when using this expression in a where clause.

Comment: *i had to use convert() to perform the - 1 second operation. whithout this a string cannot be processed with minus 1 second* Not needed. `'2020-12-16 06:15:00' - INTERVAL 1 SECOND` will work correctly.

Comment: a way cleaner solution. thank you. but am i right, there is aneed to update each expressions?

Comment: Of course, you must update all queries texts which uses incorrect expressions.

Comment: *i had to use convert() to perform the - 1 second operation.* Search Reference manual for an article about implicit type convertion during expression evaluation. You will find that in the substraction the DATETIME obtained is converted to a numeric datatype implicitly, so the result is not one you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to update each expression.  When you subtract a number from your timestamp, it first converts your timestamp into a number (e.g. 20201216061500), then you are subtracting one and, because the column you are inserting is a datetime, it tries to interpret the resulting number as a date/time, failing when the subtraction produced 20201216061499.  The correct way to subtract one second is to say `- INTERVAL 1 SECOND` or use `DATE_SUB(..., INTERVAL 1 SECOND)`.